# Gravity forms dynamically populate radio buttons empty on submit

Tags: wordpress, populate, taxonomy-terms, gravityforms

I want to add radio buttons dynamically form wordpress terms, but i they want to save it into the database. If they are required, the check will be false. Can some help to to understand why the example from gravity forms doesn't work on radio buttons?

Here my code:

```
add_filter('gform_pre_render_1', 'populate_cat_members');
add_filter('gform_pre_validation_1', 'populate_cat_members' );
add_filter('gform_pre_submission_filter_1', 'populate_cat_members' );
add_filter('gform_admin_pre_render_1', 'populate_cat_members');

function populate_cat_members($form)
{
 foreach ($form['fields'] as $field) {

 if ($field['id'] == 32) {
  $terms = get_terms('cat_members', array('hide_empty' => false, 'oderby' => 'name'));
  $choices = array();
  $numItems = count($terms);
  foreach ($terms as $post) {
    $choices[] = array('text' => $post->name, 'value' => $post->term_id);
  }
  $field->choices = $choices;
 }
}
 return $form;
}
```

Can someone help me, why i cant save the data?

Comment: Don't see anything obvioulsy wrong with the snippet but just leaving you a personal note here... Populate Anything would make this process so much eaiser. 
https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I prefer to coding my stuff by myself ;)